# Menu slide in from right and stick to right side of page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the menu below that currently slides in from the left and covers 30% of the screen from the left hand side. How do I make this slide in from the right and stick to the right side of the screen? I have tried altering the CSS line "left:-150%" to "right:-150px" but this just caused the menu to fade in where it is when you open it...

Also im looking to disable page scrolling when the menu is open...thanks!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.btn-open-menu').click(function () {
        $('header').addClass('open');
    });

    $('.link-menu').click(function () {
        $('header').removeClass('open');
    });

    $('.btn-close-menu').click(function () {
        $('header').removeClass('open');
    });
});
```

```css
 html, body {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;

}
 header {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: transparent;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 10;
     transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}


 header .btn-open-menu {
     width: 25px;
     height: 25px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50px;
     right: 50px;
     cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    header .btn-open-menu {
     top: 25px;
     right: 20px;
}
}

 header .header-content {
     width: 30%;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: #F7FCB7;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: -150%;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-content: center;
     transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
 header .header-content .btn-close-menu {
     width: 25px;
     height: 25px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 20px;
     right: 20px;
     cursor: pointer;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     flex-direction: row;
     align-content: center;
}
 header .header-content .btn-close-menu:before, header .header-content .btn-close-menu:after {
     background: #000;
     content: '';
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     height: 4px;
     position: absolute;
     transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
 header .header-content .btn-close-menu:before {
     transform: rotate(45deg);
}

 header .header-content .btn-close-menu:hover{
     transform: rotate(180deg);
     transition:0.5s ease-in-out;
}

 header .header-content .btn-close-menu:after {
     transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

 header .header-content nav {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-content: center;
}
 header .header-content nav a {
     color: #000;
     letter-spacing: 0.5px;
     line-height: 35px;
     text-decoration: none;
     transition: 0.5s;
}
 header .header-content nav a:hover {
     color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     transition: 0.5s;
}
 header .header-content .social {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     margin: 40px 0 0 0;
     font-size: 18px;
}
 header .header-content .social a {
     color: #000;
     text-decoration: none;
     margin: 0 10px;
     transition: 0.5s;
}
 header .header-content .social a:hover {
     color: #FB4D98;
     transform: scale(1.5);
     transition: 0.5s;
}
 header.open {
     height: 100vh;
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
     transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
 header.open .btn-open-menu, header.open .logo {
     opacity: 0;
     transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
 header.open .header-content {
     left: 0;
     transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
.btn-open-menu:hover {
    animation: headShake 0.5s;
}
}



 .Menu-list {
     font-family: "alliance";
     font-size: 4vw;
     line-height: 1.2;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     text-align: center;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
     .Menu-list {
     font-family: "alliance";
     font-size: 5vw;
     }
}
 .Menu-list-item {
     position: relative;
     color: transparent;
     cursor: pointer;
}

 ul.Menu-list{
     padding-inline-start: 0px !important;
     
 }
 .Menu-list-item::before {
     content: '';
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     top: 49%;
     left: -10%;
     right: -10%;
     height: 4px;
     border-radius: 4px;
     margin-top: -2px;
     background: #FB4D98;
     transform: scale(0);

     z-index: 1;
}
 .Mask {
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     overflow: hidden;
     color: #FB4D98;
     top: 0;
     height: 49%;
     transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.16, 1.08, 0.38, 0.98);
}
 .Mask span {
     display: block;
}
 .Mask + .Mask {
     top: 48.9%;
     height: 51.1%;
}
 .Mask + .Mask span {
     transform: translateY(-49%);
}
 .Menu-list-item:hover .Mask, .Menu-list-item:active .Mask {
     color: #000;
     transform: skewX(12deg) translateX(5px);
}
 .Menu-list-item:hover .Mask + .Mask, .Menu-list-item:active .Mask + .Mask {
     transform: skewX(12deg) translateX(-5px);
}
 .Menu-list-item:hover::before, .Menu-list-item:active::before {
     transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <a class="btn-open-menu">
    <span class="hamburguer"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/hamburger.png"</span>
  </a>
  
  <div class="header-content">
    <a class="btn-close-menu"></a>

    <nav>
     <div class="Menu">
  <ul class="Menu-list" data-offset="10">
    <li class="Menu-list-item" data-offset="20" onclick="location.href='/home';">
      Home
      <span class="Mask"><span>Home</span></span>
      <span class="Mask"><span>Home</span></span>
    </li>
    <li class="Menu-list-item" data-offset="16" onclick="location.href='/about';">
      About
      <span class="Mask"><span>About</span></span>
      <span class="Mask"><span>About</span></span>
    </li>
    <li class="Menu-list-item" data-offset="12" onclick="location.href='/contact';">
      Contact
      <span class="Mask"><span>Contact</span></span>
      <span class="Mask"><span>Contact</span></span>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="social">
      
      
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/jvaleskasilva/" target="_blank">
        <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
      </a>

      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/jvaleskasilva" target="_blank">
        <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></i>
      </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite easy to achieve.

```
header .header-content{left:initial; right: -100%;}
header.open .header-content{left:initial; right: 0;}
```

Comment: awesome thanks, any idea how to disable scroll on the page when menu is open?

Comment: To do this, when you add class in header  during opening the menu.
add a class on html (root element) as well. you can name it the class like "menu__opened" and then write the css like,

.menu__opened,
.menu__opened>body
{overflow: hidden;}

and remove this class while closing the menu.

Comment: thanks, i added `$('html').addClass('open');` to the JS and then added this to the CSS `html.open {
    overflow: hidden;
}`

Comment: as per your need you can disable scroll of body as well when html as open class.
because body has property of overflow scroll as well.

Comment: is there anyway to keep the scrollbar in view even though scroll is disabled?

Comment: tell me exactly where do you need scroll? if in sidebar menu then you can simply add overflow scroll css into it. for only vertical scroll set overflow-y scroll and for horizontal set overflow-x scroll

Comment: I dont need to scroll anywhere, but using the code you gave me the scrollbar disappears when the menu is opened so the website jumps to fill the space, and then jumps back again when the menu is closed to show the scrollbar again. Ideally need to keep the scrollbar in view but disable scroll functionality

Comment: `html.hidden, html.hidden>body {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 9px;
}` 
you can try something like this to prevent shaking of web page